# Spring boot layer jar and build pack

Tags: spring-boot, maven

I just started using spring boot 2.3 with layer jar and build pack feature.

Docker image is always built when

1. mvn clean install/package
2. code is committed and requested PR in git

However, this will slow down build process, how can I control the phase in which the image is being built and how can I control if image should be built at all?

Following is configuration that added to pom file

```
<plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <layers>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                </layers>
                <image>
                    <name>${image.name}</name>
                    <env>
                        <BP_JVM_VERSION>${BP_JVM_VERSION}</BP_JVM_VERSION>
                    </env>
                </image>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>build-image</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

Comment: can you tell when the image should be built?

Comment: @YuriG. only want to build image when I do , for example, mvn clean install . I want to know how to control when to build image. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [`spring-boot.build-image.skip`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/html/#goals-build-image-parameters-details-skip) property

Add it to the propertied with `true` value

```
<properties>
    <spring-boot.build-image.skip>true</spring-boot.build-image.skip>
</properties>
```

so the `build-image` goal will be skipped by default. Whenever you want to build the image pass `false` to the cmd

```
mvn clean install -Dspring-boot.build-image.skip=false
```

**Update:**

If you want to change the phase from `install` to `package`, you need to configure the plugin as following:

```
<executions>
   <execution>
      <id>default</id>
      <phase>none</phase>
      <goals>
         <goal>build-image</goal>
      </goals>
   </execution>
   <execution>
      <id>build-image-during-package</id>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
         <goal>build-image</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
 </executions>
```

Comment: thanks. but i am looking to control image build in either maven install / package command

Comment: @xibrian I've added the configuration that is needed to change the phase

Comment: I have added those changes, but when i ran mvn clean package -DskipTests or mvn clean install -DskipTests. both command will create images.

Comment: @xibrian sorry, I don't understand what you are trying to achieve

Comment: when ran mvn clean install -DskipTests, i do not want to build images . but only build images when i do mvn clean package -DskipTests

Comment: mvn package is part of the mvn install lifecycle https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html.  So you cannot achieve this without using a profile or passing a build argument

Answer (score 2):

The `build-image` goal is attached to the `package` phase by default. It is run each time the `package` goal is run because of the `executions` configuration you have in your pom.xml:

```
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>build-image</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
```

If you remove this `<executions>` block, `build-image` will not be run automatically, but can be run manually with `mvn spring-boot:build-image`.

Alternatively, you can attach the goal to a different phase like `install` by specifying the phase in the `<execution>` block like this:

```
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>build-image</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have tried the alternative approach by having phase install. However, when i ran mvn clean package, the docker image is still created. I believe that the expected behavior is that "mvn clean install" will create impage, and "mvn clean package" will not